# question on documentation convention for heat PDE used by Finite Elements methods in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, documentation, heat-equation

Why FEM documentation says heat PDE is second order in time? This makes it looking same as the wave PDE.  Is this meant to be that $m=0$ for the heat pde? But this looks confusing. Could this be just a typo, or there is some convention I am overlooking?  I also noticed the second order of time term is a little bit grayed out compared to the rest of the terms in the PDE. May be then this is meant to be ignored?  But if this is the case, I do not think this is a good way to present it. Depending on font and color and eye sight, it is hard to distinguish somewhat grayed letters from non grayed ones and it is easy to overlook this.

[FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html)

This screen shot is from the above page, about 5 pages down from top the page:

[image]

Comment: Note that the second derivative term is greyed out. This means it is not active for the heat equation.

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I guess that what it is. But this is really confusing ways to do it. May be using different colors would have been more clear. So black colored terms are the relevant ones, and Red colored ones to be ignored. This would make it more clear to read. Right now, hard to notice this difference between gray and black. I thought it is my monitor was not good and getting old and only noticed the different shades later on but not at first. This is in addition that the formulas are in smaller fonts than the rest of the text.  WRI should use Latex for documentation.

Comment: Would it help if I added a sentence like: "In the following the grayed out terms do not contribute to the PDE at hand, only the black, active terms contribute.

Comment: Actually the sentence is there: What follows are some well-known PDEs and their corresponding coefficients. To illustrate the generality of (1), the components that are relevant to a specific equation are black, while the non-relevant components are gray.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a sentence in the documentation just above it that says:

> What follows are some well-known PDEs and their corresponding coefficients. To illustrate the generality of (1), the components that
> are relevant to a specific equation are black, while the non- relevant
> components are gray.

FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM#1102771966

or [online](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1102771966)

I have now changed the black components to red. I hope that makes it visually more obvious. This is what it looks in the source notebook now

[image]

This change will be visible in from version 13.1 onward.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that much later. But I think using Latex and the cancel package would make things much more clear. I'll post an example below.

Comment: @Nasser, sure, it you could make a suggestion I can see if it's feasible.

Comment: "I have now changed the black components to red." Yes, that will be much more clear. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The math on those pages is not really clear. The fonts of the math equation for some reason are much smaller. The math is not vector graphics also. They are gif files.

I just wrote this above section  in Latex. Here is the result (at the bottom, there are links to all of these files). Another advantage of using Latex is that PDF comes for free. Many people here ask for PDF for documentation all the time. I know it takes more time to do this in Latex. But Mathematica has very good TeXForm command. The rest is just matter of making Makefiles and collecting different parts (images, animations, etc...) into one final document.

---

[image]

[image]

---

For me, the above is much more readable than using different shades of gray and the math is font size is same as the text, not smaller.
And before someone complains, but what about HTML? The above compiles as is to HTML and also uses `mathjax`, which allows one to copy the Latex of each formula from the web page if needed and even increase the size of the math if they want. Here is screen shot of the web page. It also possible to generate .svg for math instead of using mathjax. .svg is vector graphics. The command to compile to pdf used `lualatex` and to html used `make4ht`. All of these are build into TeXLive and are free.

---

[image]

---

The Latex used is the following. Compiled to PDF and HTML using TexLive 2021.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}   
\section*{The Coefficient Form of Partial Differential Equations}

What types of equations can be solved with the finite element method as implemented in \verb|NDSolve|? 
Consider a single partial differential equation in $u$:

\[
m \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + d \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + 
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u - \alpha u + \gamma \right) + 
\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u - f = 0 \tag{1}
\]

The PDE is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $u$ is the dependent variable for which a solution is sought. 
The coefficients $m$,$d$,$a$ and $f$ are scalars; $\alpha,\gamma$ and $\beta$ are
vectors; and $c$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

What follows are some well-known PDEs and their corresponding coefficients. To illustrate 
the generality of (1), the components that are relevant to a specific equation 
are black, while the non-relevant components are crossed out.

The Laplace equation simply contains a diffusive term:
%
\[
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) + 
 {\cancel{\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u - f}} = 0 
\]
%
To model Poisson's equation, only a small modification is needed; add a load term $f$:
%
\[
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) + 
 {\cancel{\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u}} - f = 0 
\]
%
Helmholtz's equation adds a reaction term :
\[
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) + 
 {\cancel{\beta \cdot \triangledown u}} + a u - f = 0 
\]
%
Convection-diffusion-reaction type equations are another common class of PDEs. Compared to 
the previous examples, these have an additional convection term  $\beta \cdot \triangledown u$:
%
\[
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) + 
\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u - f = 0 
\]
%
The PDEs considered so far are stationary, i.e. they have no time dependence. The heat 
equation adds time dependence to the Poisson equation. It has the following form:
\[
{\cancel{m \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}}} + d \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + 
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) 
+{\cancel{\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u}} - f = 0 
\]
%
Similarly, the wave equation is given as:
\[
m \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + {\cancel{d \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}}} + 
\triangledown  \cdot \left( -c \triangledown u\,\, {\cancel{- \alpha u + \gamma}}\right) 
+{\cancel{\beta \cdot \triangledown u + a u - f}} = 0 
\]

Equation (1) provides the components for modeling a range of different phenomena, since it provides 
spatial derivatives up to order $2$.

\end{document}
```

Link to files  [HTML](https://12000.org/tmp/FEM_docs/foo2.htm)  [PDF](https://12000.org/tmp/FEM_docs/foo2.pdf)   [Latex file](https://12000.org/tmp/FEM_docs/foo2.tex)

Comment: I would need to do this strike out in the source notebook. These html files are generated the those. So a latex or html solution is not a viable path. I agree with your assessment that the web pages look somewhat poor; additionally things like equation number are missing... I think it's better to read the things in the documentation center.